# Проблема с JSON, в скрипте python. Ошибка с синтаксисом

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot

Имею скрипт бота для тг.

Установил зависимости, переменные для окружения.

При запуске выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/bot/bot_garant/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import loader
  File "/root/bot/bot_garant/loader.py", line 20, in <module>
    log = get_logger('')
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/bot/bot_garant/utils/logging.py", line 15, in get_logger
    dict_config = json.load(f)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

понял, что проблема с исполнением кода JSON, а именно с синтаксисом, но не могу понять где копать. В каком именно файле. помогите пожалуйста!

Файл logging.py(отрезок отвечающий за JSON):

```
    create_logs_folder()
    with open(config.LOGGING_CONFIG_FILE, "r") as f:
        logging.config.dictConfig(json.load(f))
    return logging.getLogger("default")
```

logger.JSON:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s - %(processName)-10s - %(name)-10s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "default"
        },
        "rotating_file": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "level": "WARNING",
            "formatter": "default",
            "filename": "logs/main.log",
            "maxBytes": 10485760,
            "backupCount": 20,
            "encoding": "utf8"
        },
        "telegram": {
            "class": "utils.telegram_errors_handler.TelegramHandler",
            "level": "ERROR",
            "formatter": "default",
            "bot_token": "",
            "admin_id": "",
            "bot_name": ""
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "default": {
            "handlers": ["console", "rotating_file", "telegram"],
            "level": "DEBUG"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте print(f.read()) перед этой строкой с парсингом json и посмотрите что там в содержимом. Если валидный json, отпишите здесь.

Comment: @Alpensin немного не понял куда вставлять, ну ладно. Я так елнял, что он ищет файл loggers.json но не может его найти. Я дал путь к файлу, но он опять его не видит.. File "/root/bot/bot_garant/utils/logging.py", line 19, in get_logger
    dict_config["loggers.json"][name] = dict_config["loggers.json"][template]

Comment: Исходник файла JSON в студию

Comment: @Namerek указал...

Comment: Файл он находит, но файл то пустой, судя по всему. Сделайте `print(config.LOGGING_CONFIG_FILE`, чтобы понять, какой же файл читается. И сделайте `with open(config.LOGGING_CONFIG_FILE, "r") as f: print(f.read())`, чтобы проверить содержимое файла.